# Wall outlet receptacle amperage for 1500 watt electricle kettle

Tags: electrical, receptacle

I live in NY. After running for few days, my wall outlet is not powering my electric kettle so I guess I need a new one. Following is the electrical info of my electric kettle:

Voltage     120 Volts
1500 watt element for fast heating 
60 Hz

What amperage should my wall outlet receptacle be of? I see 15 amp and 20 amp options on Amazon.

Comment: What exactly are you asking about? Replacing the kettle or the wall outlet?

Comment: Most wall outlets are of the 15 amp class(but can be used on 20 amp circuits).  Most plugged in appliances(kettles/toasters) are made for 15 amp circuits(recommended to be used on 20 amp circuits).  Have you checked the breaker?

Comment: 1,500 watts at 120 volts is 12.5 amps.  A 15 amp circuit could supply up to 1,800 watts (15*120)  which is 1,800 watts .    I don't think it needs to be derated bc it's probably not considered a "continuous load"  but even if it did need to be derated by 20% a 15 amp circuit would be rated to 12 amps or 1,440 watts, just sneaking past the rules.  My question is: Does the kettle work on other circuits?   For years kitchen circuits were required to be 20 amps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, try the kettle in the bathroom or other place with a standard outlet.  If the kettle does not work there, it is burned out and the kitchen socket is probably fine.

1500 watt is a standard maximum size for 120 plug-in appliances in North America.  As the math suggests, they are 12.5 amps*. Those work with a standard 120V outlet.

If you are from overseas and are accustomed to faster kettles, there's a reason for that...

[image]

The socket is unlikely to fail. It is just metal and plastic.  However the connections in the back of it can fail, and other things can happen too.

Now, are you renting? If so you need to get permission from your landlord to remove the outlet. They may say "let me send my electrician over" and that would be that.

Next, search to see if any other outlets are also not working.  Go around with a lamp or phone charger.  If more than one outlet is out, check the circuit breaker. Turn it off, then on.  If that does not fix it,  it's probably time for a pro.

Socket "back stab" connections are not allowed on 20 amp kitchen circuits, and wrong torque is a common reason for outlet failure. A torque screwdriver is now required on any outlet that specifies a torque.

* not *exxxxactly* because of subtleties in how UL rates things.  See comments.

Comment: Harper, this is the 2nd time you've got this a little messed up. The 1500 W of the typical space heater or kettle and the 1875 W of the typical hair dryer is based on 15A x 12**5**V. 15 x 125 = 1875. 1875 x .8 = 1500. It isn't 12.5A. Yes, most homes are closer to 120V service, but the math for these things is based on 125V. Thanks to Ohm's law, a pure resistive load will end up using less current at lower voltage (you reminded me of that once when I got it wrong). Using the 1500W example, that's 10.4167 Ohms. So at 125V you get 1500W and 12A. At 120V you get 11.52 A and 1382W. If you're

Comment: selling kettles or space heaters, you'll advertise that 1500W - nice round number and most importantly it is bigger than the number for 110V, 115V or 120V, so it will sell better (more power!).

Comment: @manassehkatz because that detail only adds confusion for the novice. If I say "11.52 amps at 120V" they go "wait, that doesn't sound right!"

Comment: But anyone who looks up the derate rules (or reads them on numerous other posts) will say: But 12.5/15 = 83% and it should be 80%.

Comment: But your footnote helps. +1

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact   Have to agree with harper on this.  Some you keep simple, some you get into details.

Answer (score 0):

Kitchens are supposed to have at least two 20 Amp circuits and can have 15 Amp outlets. They are supposed to be GFCI protected so check to see if you have outlets with the "test" /"reset" buttons and press the reset.

Answer (score 0):

It used to work, then it stopped working.

`After running for few days, my wall outlet is not powering my electric kettle`

Usually that indicates a breaker. Often it is not very visible that breaker tripped, so push it anyway.

This all is assuming the kettle works on another circuit.

Answer (score 0):

A 15 amp receptacle is adequate for your kettle.  First check if there is power at the wall outlet.  Plug in something, a desk lamp, say, that is known to work.  If the power is on, then the problem is the kettle.  If power is off, check any GFCI (Ground Fault Current Interrupt) receptacles; your kitchen should have these, but the outlet you are using the kettle on might be fed from a GFCI at another receptacle.  So check all the receptacles for a tripped GFCI.  Push the reset button.  If that doesn't do it, next check your panel (and any subpanels you might have) for a tripped breaker.  If no power and no tripped breaker is found, then you might have a bad receptacle or wiring, but that less common.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to add that outlets *can* wear out over time, especially if abused. I have a few that don't make good contact with all plugs and really need to be replaced. But that's easy to test, as others have pointed out: if the device works fine plugged in elsewhere, the problem is this outlet or it's circuit.